# PyDev: @DynamicAttrs for modules

Tags: python, aptana, pydev, code-analysis

In the program I am writing, I created a module called `settings` that declares a few constants but loads other from a configuration file, placing them in the module namespace (for example: the value of π might be in the code of the module, but the weight of the user in a configuration file).

This is such that in other modules, I can do:

```
from settings import *
```

Everything works fine for me but - using Aptana Studio / PyDev, the code analysis tool throws a lot of `undefined variable errors` like this:

[image]

I found [here](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_code_analysis.html) that there is a flag usable to prevent this behaviour in class docstrings, but it has no effect if I try to use it at module level. So I wonder two things:

- **Is there a way to selectively get rid of these errors** (meaning that I wouldn't want to completely turn off the option "mark as errors the undefined variables": in other modules it could in fact be an error)?
- If not, **is there an alternative pattern to achieve what I want** in terms of wild imports, but without confusing the code analysis tool?

**Pre-emptive note**: I am perfectly aware of the fact wild imports are discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you'd probably have the same error even if it wasn't a wild import (i.e.: import settings / settings.MY_VARIABLE would still show an error because the code-analysis can't find it).

Aside from the `@UndefinedVariable` in each place that references it (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will show that option), I think that a better pattern for your module would be:

```
MY_VARIABLE = 'default value'
...

update_default_values() # Go on and override the defaults.
```

That way, the code-analysis (and anyone reading your module), would know which variables are expected.

Otherwise, if you don't know them before, I think a better approach would be having a method (i.e.: `get_settings('MY_VARIABLE')`).

Unrelated to the actual problem. I'd really advise against using a wild import here (nor even importing the constant... i.e.: `from settings import MY_VARIABLE`).

A better approach for a settings module is always using:

```
import settings
settings.MY_VARIABLE
```

(because otherwise, if any place decides it wants to change the MY_VARIABLE, any place that has put the reference in its own namespace will probably never get the changed variable).

An even safer approach would be having a method `get_setting('var')`, as it would allow you to a better lazy-loading of your preferences (i.e.: don't load on import, but when it's called the 1st time).

Comment: Firstly: thank you for having created PyDev! It's probably one of the most useful pieces of codes in my life as developer! :) Secondly, thanks for the alternate suggestions. At the end I am refactoring my code with `import settings as S` and then `S.<constant-name-here>` in the code. It's concise enough for me and makes code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl-1 on an error and choose `@UndefinedVariable` or type `#@UndefinedVariable` on a line that has an error you want to ignore.

You can try to add your module to be scanned by the PyDev interpreter by going to Window > Preferences, then PyDev > Interpreter - Python. Under the Libraries tab, click `New Folder` and browse to the directory that contains `settings`, then click `Apply`. Hopefully, Pydev will find your package and recognize the wildly-imported variables.